# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell in login crash loop with libmutter-2

Tags: gnome, login, gnome-shell, mutter

I have a problem with the login with GNOME3 (3.28.4) since one day ago. I have Ubuntu 18.04, my default desktop is GNOME. At some point, without any change in my configuration files, I could not login with GNOME anymore (only my Unity desktop works). I checked the `journalctl` and the problem seems to come from `libmutter-2`. At each boot I find two error messages:

```
gnome-shell[3310]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f9975efb184 sp 00007fffcdb207b0 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f9975e9b000+159000]
gnome-shell[3321]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7e14ba6184 sp 00007fff5d8eccf0 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f7e14b46000+159000]
```

I tried already reinstalling `gnome-shell`, `mutter`, `libmutter-2-0`, I also tried removing my `gnome-shell` configuration files, etc. I also tried the usual other suggestions that are given (.Xauthority, gdm3 reconfigure, reinstall, restart) but this looks like the problem is from `mutter`. The only similar case I found was https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/190 but was solved.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I messed up with mutter today and could not login from the GUI.
I do see `.xsession-errors` file under my home directory. You may want to check if you have that file.